# Opacity через пару секунд

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такой вод код:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeElements = function(a){
    $(this).hover(function(){$(this).fadeTo(a.inTime,a.inOpacity);},function(){$(this).fadeTo(a.outTime,a.outOpacity);});
}

$(function(){
    $('#ubar').fadeElements({
        inOpacity:1,
        outOpacity:0.1,
        inTime:200,
        outTime:200
    });
});
```

Он при наводке делает плавное появление, а когда отводишь, прозрачность становится 0.1.
Как сделать, чтобы прозрачность становилась 0.1 не сразу, а через заданное кол-во милисекунд?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае исчезать будет после секундной задержки. Менять параметр **delayTime**
[Пример в действии](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/B9EF6/)

```
jQuery.fn.fadeElements = function(a){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(a.inTime,a.inOpacity);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().delay(a.delayTime).fadeTo(a.outTime,a.outOpacity);
    });
};

$(function(){
    $('#ubar').fadeElements({
        inOpacity:1,
        outOpacity:0.1,
        inTime:200,
        outTime:200,
        delayTime:1000
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. НО. Если отвести и снова подвести и держать курсор, то все равно быстренько гаснет и появляется

Comment: @inferus-vv Добавьте **.stop()**:

$(this).stop().fadeTo(a.inTime,a.inOpacity);
$(this).stop().delay(a.delayTime).fadeTo(a.outTime,a.outOpacity);

Answer (score -1):

Используя

```
window.setTimeout(<лямбда-функция или имя функции в кавычках>,<интервал>);
```

Данная функция выполнит действия, указанные в лямбда-функции через "<интервал>" миллисекунд.

Comment: по-моему, использовать в данном контексте термин "лямбда-функция" не совсем верно

Comment: имя функции в кавычках равносильно eval'у, зачем кавычки то?..

Comment: В кавычках вы передаете не результат функции, а имя функции, т.е не "function()", а "function".

Comment: Кавычки - для php, а в js функцию можно передавать и как объект. То есть, без кавычек:  
  
    function m(){alert('m');}
    setTimeout(m,2000);

Comment: @Asen - когда вы используете кавычки это равносильно eval'у.

@ling - в php тоже можно передавать безымянные функции не использую кавычки =)